# Disable 1/yes/on and 0/no/off and allow only true/false to be passed via query-param or path-param

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to disable Spring built-in deserialization of integer 0/1 and the strings
no/off yes/on that are mapped to false/true respectively when they are
passed via query-parameter or path-variable.
When any value that is not true/false is passed I want to throw IllegalArgumentException.

First I've implemented my own StringToBooleanConverter:

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class StringToBooleanConverter implements Converter<String, Boolean> {

    @Override
    public Boolean convert(String source) {
        String value = source.trim().toLowerCase();

        if ("true".equals(value)) {
            return Boolean.TRUE;
        } else if ("false".equals(value)) {
            return Boolean.FALSE;
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid boolean value '" + source + "'");
    }
}
```

And since I've provided an implementation of similar class spring will use my StringToBooleanConverter and not the one from `org.springframework.core.convert.support`

But here is where my problem arise. When I send e.g. 0 code is reaching to the `IllegalArgumentException` and then execution passed to `CustomBooleanEditor` in the
`org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors` and the method `public void setAsText(@Nullable String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {}` is invoked and does almost the same logic
as `StringToBooleanConverter`.

How can I disable Spring from calling this method and use only the `StringToBooleanConverter`?

Comment: How did you register your Converter?

Comment: I just annotated it with @Component this should tell Spring that it should 
be used.

Answer (score 0):

Try registering your `Converter` as follows:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.removeConvertible(String.class, Boolean.class);
        registry.addConverter(new StringToBooleanConverter());
    }
}
```

---

If this does not work, which I suspect. Try creating your own `CustomBooleanEditor` as follows:

```java
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public CustomBooleanEditor getCustomBooleanEditor() {
        return new CustomBooleanEditor("true", "false", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've done it but still the problem persists.
When I pass -1 or 0 as query param value it goes through my StringToBooleanConverter but
when reached to the IllegalArgumentException it transfer execution to CustomBooleanEditor
setAsText(String) method

Comment: I've edited my answer, please check it. I've added line `registry.removeConvertible(String.class, Boolean.class);` that should remove any converters from `String` to `Boolean`.

Comment: If this does not work, try the other approach.

Answer (score -1):

Configuring `ObjectMapper` disabling the following feature helped to solve the problem:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    return JsonMapper.builder()
                     .disable(MapperFeature.ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS)
                     .build();
}
```

Comment: Jackson isn't used for binding query parameters, so configuration Jackson for this won't work.